# SegmentIO analytics - Adding JSONObject inside properties

Tags: android, json, analytics, segment-io

I am trying to add JSONObject inside properties of segmentIO analytics but it is showing json as String on server.

Here is my code:

```
JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
jsonObject.addProperty("abc", "xyz");
properties.putValue("extras", jsonObject);
Analytics.with(context).track(event, properties);
```

Output:

```
extras : "{"abc","xyz"}"
```

Expected Output:

```
extras : {"abc","xyz"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JSONParser (org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser)

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject object = (JSONObject) parser.parse(json);
properties.putValue("extras", object);
```